# How to use the first value of the "next" group in r?

Tags: r

I am trying to get the first value of the next group in r to estimate a ratio. I have created a group based on the type column in my the df. Then estimated some influence factors using the sample position within the group. Finally, I am trying to estimate a ratio like this: `RRF=response/(F1*first(response)+(F2*??????))` where the `F1*first(response)` is the cal in the group but I don't know how to call the first value of the next group to finish the ratio. Can someone help with this? This is my code and my data:

```
library(dplyr)
 conc_zero_test <- zero_test %>% 
  gather(gas, response, -time,-type)%>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(type == "current_std"),gas)%>%
  mutate(X1= row_number()-1, #estimates the position of the sample within the group -1 removes std
         F1=1-(X1/n()), #relative factor influence of the cal in the current group
         F2=1-F1,       #relative factor influence of the cal in the next group
         RRF=response/(F1*first(response)+(F2*????))

structure(list(time = structure(c(1564468200, 1564475400, 1564484400, 
1564486200, 1564493400, 1564497000, 1564498800, 1564506000, 1564509600, 
1564511400, 1564518600, 1564522200, 1564524000, 1564527600, 1564531200
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), type = c("current_std", 
"n2", "n2", "current_std", "n2", "-", "current_std", "-", "n2", 
"current_std", "n2", "-", "current_std", "-", "-"), ben = c(2293951.5, 
12703.1, 6392.7, 1762512.6, 10748.4, 25468.3, 1597679, 24400.4, 
6019.4, 1510760.2, 10329.1, 29292.6, 1495942.8, 61227.5, 25379.5
), xyl = c(210975.6, 4482, 2910.8, 127612.4, 3792.6, 10295.7, 
113439.1, 10628.8, 2064.3, 107134.3, 3764.1, 10380.6, 107353.6, 
23639.1, 10317.4), cym = c(546894.5, 12202.6, 8400.8, 302091.6, 
11072.2, 16349.2, 291637.5, 18891.8, 6500.7, 276997.5, 10821.2, 
18672, 274149.4, 61379.2, 19254.7), isop = c(397288.2, 0, 0, 
239779.9, 0, 1364.8, 199081.5, 1511.2, 0, 179364, 0, 1318.4, 
174450.7, 7137.5, 9567), macr = c(221195.8, 0, 0, 138806.3, 0, 
0, 116644, 0, 0, 108893.3, 0, 0, 105689, 4325.4, 0), pin = c(50795.3, 
0, 0, 28436, 0, 1020.1, 26482.9, 925.2, 0, 27394.1, 0, 989.7, 
24344.6, 1414.7, 736.3), tmb = c(9314.5, 0, 0, 5798, 0, 0, 5136.4, 
2252.5, 0, 4542.9, 0, 0, 4398.4, 3794.4, 2186.3), tol = c(880567.1, 
7430.6, 4225.5, 569616.2, 6091.8, 65642.6, 495780.5, 52129.9, 
3226, 456079.6, 5874, 34725.9, 453944.8, 56594.4, 66148.1), mvk = c(169036.8, 
0, 0, 108738, 0, 0, 56712.5, 0, 0, 79148.9, 0, 0, 64065, 0, 0
), euc = c(12815.2, 0, 0, 8012.6, 0, 0, 5411.8, 0, 0, 5839.9, 
0, 491.7, 5450.7, 1990.8, 500.7)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(time = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
    "collector")), type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ben = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), xyl = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), cym = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), isop = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), macr = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), pin = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), tmb = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), tol = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), mvk = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), euc = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 2), class = "col_spec"))
```

Example of expected output

```
time                type        gas   response group    X1    F1    F2     RRF
  <dttm>              <chr>       <chr>    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2019-07-30 06:30:00 current_std ben   2293952.     1     0 1     0     1      
2 2019-07-30 08:30:00 n2          ben     12703.     1     1 0.667 0.333 0.006005
3 2019-07-30 11:00:00 n2          ben      6393.     1     2 0.333 0.667 0.003962
```

Comment: Are you using `dplyr` library? Please include `library(dplyr)`, if so, to make your example reproducible. For what I remember, `gather` is from `dplyr`, albeit now being replaced by `pivot_longer`.

Comment: Can you share the expected output for the data shared?

Comment: @RonakShah the RRF column is the desired output. It will be a ratio like this RRF=response /((F1*first value of the current group( response))+(F2*first value of the next group (response)). I' m missing the last bit first value of the next group (response)

Comment: Yes, I am actually looking for actual values so that we can verify our solutions.

Comment: @RonakShah I updated the question with the first expected values.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand the calculation. Can you explain? How do you get values as `1`, `0.006005` and `0.003962` ?

Comment: @RonakShah it's the equation I wrote in the comment. For example for the second value of 0.006005 is RRF=12703/(0.667*2293952+0.333*1762512.6). Most of the elements in the calculation are from the same row response, F1 and F2. The difference is the first value of the group 2294952 and the first value of the next group 1762512.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a self-join to get the first `response` of the next group:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# the OPs example data (long!)
zero_test <-
  structure(
    list(
      time = structure(
        c(
          1564468200,
          1564475400,
          1564484400,
          1564486200,
          1564493400,
          1564497000,
          1564498800,
          1564506000,
          1564509600,
          1564511400,
          1564518600,
          1564522200,
          1564524000,
          1564527600,
          1564531200
        ),
        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
        tzone = "UTC"
      ),
      type = c(
        "current_std",
        "n2",
        "n2",
        "current_std",
        "n2",
        "-",
        "current_std",
        "-",
        "n2",
        "current_std",
        "n2",
        "-",
        "current_std",
        "-",
        "-"
      ),
      ben = c(
        2293951.5,
        12703.1,
        6392.7,
        1762512.6,
        10748.4,
        25468.3,
        1597679,
        24400.4,
        6019.4,
        1510760.2,
        10329.1,
        29292.6,
        1495942.8,
        61227.5,
        25379.5
      ),
      xyl = c(
        210975.6,
        4482,
        2910.8,
        127612.4,
        3792.6,
        10295.7,
        113439.1,
        10628.8,
        2064.3,
        107134.3,
        3764.1,
        10380.6,
        107353.6,
        23639.1,
        10317.4
      ),
      cym = c(
        546894.5,
        12202.6,
        8400.8,
        302091.6,
        11072.2,
        16349.2,
        291637.5,
        18891.8,
        6500.7,
        276997.5,
        10821.2,
        18672,
        274149.4,
        61379.2,
        19254.7
      ),
      isop = c(
        397288.2,
        0,
        0,
        239779.9,
        0,
        1364.8,
        199081.5,
        1511.2,
        0,
        179364,
        0,
        1318.4,
        174450.7,
        7137.5,
        9567
      ),
      macr = c(
        221195.8,
        0,
        0,
        138806.3,
        0,
        0,
        116644,
        0,
        0,
        108893.3,
        0,
        0,
        105689,
        4325.4,
        0
      ),
      pin = c(
        50795.3,
        0,
        0,
        28436,
        0,
        1020.1,
        26482.9,
        925.2,
        0,
        27394.1,
        0,
        989.7,
        24344.6,
        1414.7,
        736.3
      ),
      tmb = c(
        9314.5,
        0,
        0,
        5798,
        0,
        0,
        5136.4,
        2252.5,
        0,
        4542.9,
        0,
        0,
        4398.4,
        3794.4,
        2186.3
      ),
      tol = c(
        880567.1,
        7430.6,
        4225.5,
        569616.2,
        6091.8,
        65642.6,
        495780.5,
        52129.9,
        3226,
        456079.6,
        5874,
        34725.9,
        453944.8,
        56594.4,
        66148.1
      ),
      mvk = c(169036.8,
              0, 0, 108738, 0, 0, 56712.5, 0, 0, 79148.9, 0, 0, 64065, 0, 0),
      euc = c(
        12815.2,
        0,
        0,
        8012.6,
        0,
        0,
        5411.8,
        0,
        0,
        5839.9,
        0,
        491.7,
        5450.7,
        1990.8,
        500.7
      )
    ),
    class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-15L),
    spec = structure(list(
      cols = list(
        time = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime",
                                                      "collector")),
        type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                           "collector")),
        ben = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                          "collector")),
        xyl = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                          "collector")),
        cym = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                          "collector")),
        isop = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                           "collector")),
        macr = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                           "collector")),
        pin = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                          "collector")),
        tmb = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                          "collector")),
        tol = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                          "collector")),
        mvk = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                          "collector")),
        euc = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                          "collector"))
      ),
      default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
                                            "collector")),
      skip = 2
    ), class = "col_spec")
  )

temp1 <- zero_test %>% 
  gather(gas, response, -time,-type) %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(type == "current_std"), gas) %>%
  mutate(X1= row_number()-1, #estimates the position of the sample within the group -1 removes std
         F1=1-(X1/n()), #relative factor influence of the cal in the current group
         F2=1-F1,
         first_response = first(response)) %>% 
  ungroup

conc_zero_test <- temp1 %>% 
  left_join(y = {temp1 %>%
                  mutate(group = group - 1) %>% 
                  select(gas, group, first_response_next = first_response) %>% 
                  distinct},
            by = c("gas", "group")) %>% 
  mutate(RRF = response / ((F1 * first_response) + (F2 * first_response_next)))

conc_zero_test
#> # A tibble: 150 x 11
#>    time                type  gas   response group    X1    F1    F2
#>    <dttm>              <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2019-07-30 06:30:00 curr… ben   2293952.     1     0 1     0    
#>  2 2019-07-30 08:30:00 n2    ben     12703.     1     1 0.667 0.333
#>  3 2019-07-30 11:00:00 n2    ben      6393.     1     2 0.333 0.667
#>  4 2019-07-30 11:30:00 curr… ben   1762513.     2     0 1     0    
#>  5 2019-07-30 13:30:00 n2    ben     10748.     2     1 0.667 0.333
#>  6 2019-07-30 14:30:00 -     ben     25468.     2     2 0.333 0.667
#>  7 2019-07-30 15:00:00 curr… ben   1597679      3     0 1     0    
#>  8 2019-07-30 17:00:00 -     ben     24400.     3     1 0.667 0.333
#>  9 2019-07-30 18:00:00 n2    ben      6019.     3     2 0.333 0.667
#> 10 2019-07-30 18:30:00 curr… ben   1510760.     4     0 1     0    
#> # … with 140 more rows, and 3 more variables: first_response <dbl>,
#> #   first_response_next <dbl>, RRF <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>